# How to populate conandata.yml?

Tags: python, yaml, conan

Is there any way to write anything to conandata.yml file? I want calculate execution time of code and populate my conandata.yml with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `update_conandata()` that you can use in your `export()` method:

```
import os
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.files import update_conandata


class Pkg(ConanFile):
    name = "pkg"
    version = "0.1"

    def export(self):
        update_conandata(self, {"mydata": {...}})
```

However I am not sure this is a good practice. Conan packages should be reproducible, and `conan create .` should result in always the same `conandata`. The `conandata.yml` is a place to store information that is source for the recipe to work, not to store arbitrary metadata about the code or other stuff, so it sounds abuse of the conandata feature.

Comment: Yeah, I am able write things to the conandata.yml using export. But the problem I am facing is I want to calculate the package creation time and save it into the conandata.yml. Since export() is the first method which is being called I cannot save the execution time in it

Comment: You can use [Hooks](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html) and do it as last step, on `post_package_info`. The conandata.yml path can be captured by the conanfile path. More explanation [here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/extending/hooks.html) and as real example, use [ConanCenterIndex hooks](https://github.com/conan-io/hooks/).

Comment: conandata.yml only exists 1, per recipe, and it is immutable once it has been exported, so it cannot be modified per-package or after a package has been built. It is part of the input recipe, while the package is an output. You can certainly create other json files in the build and package steps, and package them, but ``conandata.yml`` is not possible to be modified, it breaks the recipe immutability promise.

Answer (score 0):

You could create yaml files or edit existing ones using the [PyYAML library](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#FrequentlyAskedQuestions). You can install it via `pip` and import the library in one line using `from yaml import load, dump`. The code to load your `conandata.yml` file, make changes to it such as adding execution times where relevant and save it would look something like this:

```
from yaml import load, dump

data = load(file('conandata.yml', 'r'), Loader=Loader)

# ... make changes, calculate and add execution times ...

output = dump(data, file('conandata.yml', 'w'))
```

The library's documentation will help you find exactly what you need: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: I tried this. This is what I usually do with the normal yaml files but with conan yaml file it does not let me open it. Exits with the code error "Unsupported Format"

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?